# Dynamically style half of a pageBlockSection title

Tags: visualforce

On a Visualforce app, I have a pageBlockSection with a title provided by a facet header:

```
<style>
.red
   {color: red;}
.green
   {color: green;}
</style>
<apex:pageBlockSection  id="pbs">
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="{!IF(variable1=='Positive','green','red')}">Uncoloured: Coloured</apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>  
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And right now it comes out as entirely green or entirely red. How could I make it so that only the second half appear as coloured whilst the first half remains black.
e.g. Uncoloured(black): Coloured(red/green).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple elements inside the `apex:facet`, so you just need to shuffle some things around. Also, the `apex:outputPanel` is unnecessary here; you can use merge syntax in normal HTML, too.

```
<apex:facet name="header">
    Uncoloured: <span class="{!IF(variable1=='Positive','green','red')}">Coloured</span>
</apex:facet>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much!